# Can't return byte[ ] with security=Message

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security

In my solution I decide to change `SecurityMode` to `Message` and `MessageCredentialType` to `UserName`. Unfortunately after that, when I try to call method whitch returns `byte[]`, sevice *throws timeout*.

Is there any possibility to return `byte[]` or I must *wrap* this?

Comment: Show us some code please

Comment: Have you tried `obj.ToByteArray()` or `obj.GetBytes()`? Some code might help us narrow down your problem

Comment: byte[] to be return from wcf is totally fine. so problem is something else

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue. Problem was with too large byte array which I tried to send with message.

When I change securityMode to TransportWithMessageCredential and use TransferMode = Streamed everything works fine.

Please correct me if I wrong.